# Android ADB. Weird behaviour

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb

All of a sudden adb on my machine take weird behaviour, I can not debug any projects. 
I use Intellij Idea on Ubuntu 12.10. Two days ago all working fine, but now debugger won't working in general.
`adb devices` shows all attached devices, when I start application on phone I can see dialog with message `Waiting for debugger`, but any breakpoints not working. I don't know what can be a reason this situation, I just install Netbeans.
Please help who know how resolve this situation. Without debugger my work is really hell

Comment: In Eclipse debugger not working also

Comment: Does an emulator work?  If its a device, can you let us know what version its runnning.  also verify in intellij,  Tools > Android > that "enabled adb service" is CHECKED.

Comment: Debugging in emulator not working, it is real device with Android 4.0.4, "enable adb integration" checked, but I don't think what it is problem in intellij

Comment: Hmm,  maybe its the usb cable.  Can you try using a different one or different device (one that works).

Comment: Yes, I try change a cable but without results

Comment: I found problem, debugger working fine in IU-123.139(I found old version), but in IU-129.298 is not. It is Intellij Idea problem

Comment: Known issue, will be fixed in the next update.